# 500 Internal Server error after changing document root

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am using wamp server . I have a folder Retailer located inside the www folder. There is sub folder public inside this Retailer folder which contains index.php file. I am trying to change the document root to this public folder. Here is what I have done with .htaccess

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName local.Retailer
    DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\Retailer\public"      \\update

    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"

    <Directory "C:\wamp\www\Retailer\public">       \\update
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
        RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But when I try to access localhost/Retailer I get internal server 500 error. What am I doing wrong?

Ahmar

Comment: _“What am I doing wrong?”_ – you’re asking this question without having looked into the error log …

Comment: @CBroe how do I look at error log? I am new to this. I don't think this deserves a down vote :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VirtualHost must be written on httpd.conf or included files, not in .htaccess
move this configuration to the right file and it will work

Answer (score 0):

What you have *can't be in an htaccess file*.

The `<VirtualHost>` container is reserved for server/vhost config, not htaccess.

The `ServerName` and `DocumentRoot` directives, are not allowed in an htaccess file.

The `<Directory>` container is reserved for server/vhost config, not htaccess (which is essentially a per-directory application)

The `AllowOverride` is not allowed in htaccess, it's a directive that essentially defines what is allowed and what isn't allowed to be overridden in an htaccess file. Makes no sense to allow an htaccess file to define that.

These directives are the only part of that file that you are allowed to have:

```
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"

    DirectoryIndex index.php

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

If you are trying to change the *document root*, then you need to go into your vhost/server config, and look for the line that says:

```
DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\Retailer"
```

and change that to:

```
DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\Retailer\public"
```

Comment: Thanks but then how do I fix it?,

Comment: @AhmarAli by removing it all and reading the bottom of my answer where it says to change the document root in your server/vhost config